# How to filter a column in dataframe starting with integers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have used the following codes:

```
data_snp_old=data_snp_age[data_snp_age['Age'].str.contains('15+', na = False)] 
data_snp_old=data_snp_age.filter(regex='^15+', axis=0)
```

The codes are not working perfectly i.e they are filtering but some rows with <15 enteries is also coming.

[image]

Comment: your age column is a string so you can't filter it with integer logic, what are you trying to do? grab all rows that `<= 15` ? can you post 5 rows of your dataframe as text?

Comment: I am using str.contain() but still, the result is not giving all the rows that have age 15+. I am trying to filter out all the rows that have age as 15+.

Comment: @AvinashKr Please post the dataframe and the expected output as text. It will help you in getting help faster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the expression you're using in the `contains()` function. Rather than considering '15+' as a character sequence it is being considered as a regex. Hence it is matching both the conditions.

Function definition:
`Series.str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan, regex=True)`

```
Parameter :
pat : Character sequence or regular expression.
case : If True, case sensitive.
flags : Flags to pass through to the re module, e.g. re.IGNORECASE.
na : Fill value for missing values.
regex : If True, assumes the pat is a regular expression.

Returns : Series or Index of boolean values
```

Here's what you can do instead:

```
import pandas as pd
# Making a toy data-set.
data={'Category':['Age','Age','Age','Age','Age'],'Age':['15+','<15','15+','<15','15+']}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)
# Output: 
  Category  Age
0      Age  15+
1      Age  <15
2      Age  15+
3      Age  <15
4      Age  15+
```

Here's the important part:

```
df_new=df[df['Age'].str.contains('15+', na = False,regex=False)]
# Tell contains() to not consider the expression as a regex by default.
print(df_new)
# Output:
  Category  Age
0      Age  15+
2      Age  15+
4      Age  15+
```

**Or**

```
df_new=df[df['Age'].str.contains(r'(\d{2}\+)', na = False)]
# the above regex matches a group in which two digits should be followed by a +
print(df_new)
# Output:
  Category  Age
0      Age  15+
2      Age  15+
4      Age  15+
```

Here's some stuff to read for further reference:

- [Pandas Series.str.contains()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-contains/)

**Hope this helps, cheers!**